# instead of arrayCollection

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

I am trying to return values from java into flex front end using BlazeDs.Successfully blazeds is connecting while retrieving the values it is showing [object Asynvtoken] am not getting values from java method.

My flex code is:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            public function get_user():void
            {
                var token:AsyncToken = ro.getOperation('getUser').send();
                user_grid.dataProvider = token.toString();
                Alert.show(user_grid.dataProvider.toString());
            }
            private function fault(e:FaultEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("code:\n" + e.fault.faultCode  + "\n\nMessage:\n" + e.fault.faultString + "\n\nDetail:\n" + e.fault.faultDetail);
            }
            private function result(e:ResultEvent):void
            {
                userbtn.visible = false;
                lnkbtn.visible = true;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:RemoteObject id="ro"
                        source="com.freelancer.GetUser"
                        fault="fault(event)"
                        destination="BlazeDsService">
            <s:method name="getUser"
                      result="result(event)"/>
        </s:RemoteObject>
    </fx:Declarations>

        <mx:DataGrid id="user_grid" x="-1" y="-1" width="705" height="356">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Id" dataField="id"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Password" dataField="pwd"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>      

    <s:Button x="322" y="429" id="userbtn" label="Get User" width="98" 
              height="23" cornerRadius="10" click="get_user()"/>
    <mx:LinkButton x="331" y="429" id="lnkbtn" visible="false" label="Connected Please Wait Loading . . ."/>
```

My java code is:

```
public class GetUser
{
    public static void main(String[] argv) 
    {
        System.out.println("-------- PostgreSQL " +
                "JDBC Connection Testing ----------");
        getUser();
    }
    public static List<User> getUser()
    {
         List<User> ls=new ArrayList<User>();   
         String host = "test";
            String port = "1234";
            String dbName = "test";
        Connection connection = null;
        try 
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName,"user", "user");

            System.out.println("Database is connected");    

         String strSQL = "select * from test";
         Statement st = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(strSQL);
         System.out.println("hi,query executed");
         while(rs.next())
         {
             User user = new User();
             user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
             user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
             user.setPwd(rs.getString("pwd"));
             ls.add(user);
         }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignored) 
            {

            }
        }
         return ls;
    }
}
```

Please help me if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5960343/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that calls to RPC services are asynchronous.

At first you call the remote function `getUser`. This request is send to the server and the `getOperation` function returns immediatly. The result of this call is an `AsyncToken` object which is not the result of the call of `getUser`. The token is a part of the [*Asynchronous Completion Token design pattern*](http://www1.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/ACT.pdf).
After the RPC function returns your client will get the response in the result handler which is your declared `result` function. The result is part of the `ResultEvent` parameter.

So the following should work:

```
    public function get_user():void
    {
        var token:AsyncToken = ro.getOperation('getUser').send();
    }

    private function result(e:ResultEvent):void
    {
        user_grid.dataProvider = e.result;     
        userbtn.visible = false;
        lnkbtn.visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have got some information related to asynchronous calls.But still my problem is not yet solved.I followed yours steps now it is not retrieving anything showing blank gird. Is there any errors i have done in my code.Please let me know.I am trying a lot to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance,
Ravi

Comment: You can't expect us to fix everything for you.  Use the debugger, check to see if you're receiving any data, and that the data is added properly to grid, etc...